# Laravel Eloquent Union query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

So I have the following query:

```
$a = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
    ->where('col_a', '=' , 1)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))

$b = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
    ->where('col_b', '=' , 1)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))

$a->union($b)->get();
```

No sorting is happening when I 'orderBy()' first and then union.

When I do query '$a' or '$b' individually the 'orderBy()' works fine.

When I do it in the following way 'orderBy()' happens as a whole.

```
$a->union($b)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))
    ->get();
```

How can I make it so the 'orderBy()' applies for each individually and then union the results back? It seems like it should work.

EDIT: If anyone can provide a way to do this, even if it's normal MySQL, I will choose yours as the answer as I think there may be a bug with Eloquent.

Comment: Why it "doesn't work". What is the error or the output

Comment: There's no error. It just doesn't seem to apply the orderBy sorting.

Comment: It's not an Eloquent thing, it's a MySQL thing. See the "Followup" in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683766/how-to-use-order-by-inside-union. Basically: ORDER BY will be disregarded in UNIONs, and may be even dependent on the version of MySQL.

Answer (score 37):

Try the following:

```
$a = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
->where('col_a', '=' , 1);

$b = Model::where('code', '=', $code)->where('col_b', '=' , 1)
->union($a)
->get();

$result = $b;
```

Comment: But in case both tables have diff numbers of columns it gives error. Is there any way I can use UNION in eloquent with diff columns tables ?

Comment: @Sunil For me, that is impossible to union in different number of columns,. unless you will add select allies with null value,.

Comment: Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns.
The columns must also have similar data types.
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order.

Answer (score 11):

Just try to apply `orderBy()` after `union()`

Try this

```
$a->union($b)->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))->get();
```

**EDIT**

Researched about and found and prepared eloquent query just try this

```
$modelA = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
    ->where('col_a', '=' , 1)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))

$modelB = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
    ->where('col_b', '=' , 1)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))

$a = DB::table(DB::raw("({$modelA->toSql()}) as a"))
    ->mergeBindings($modelA->getQuery())
    ->selectRaw("a.*");

$b = DB::table(DB::raw("({$modelB->toSql()}) as b"))
    ->mergeBindings($modelB->getQuery())
    ->selectRaw("b.*");

$a->union($b)->get();
```

Comment: I don't want it ordered as a whole. I want the individual queries to be ordered within themselves.

Comment: can you post the result without union and with union to get know more about the problems

Comment: It would be difficult because I simplified the query for the question. 

Basically no sorting is happening when I orderBy() first and then union. 

When I do them individually the orderBy() works fine.

When I do it based on the answer you posted orderBy() happens as a whole.

Comment: I think this may be a Laravel bug. I posted the bug on github. Hopefully it will get resolved soon.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Checking now.

Comment: Sec, I'll try that.

Comment: It didn't work. I checked what it was bringing back and it had way more info than it should be displaying, like server login and password info.

Answer (score 10):

The **"merge"** function in Laravel collection might be able to help you. 
The big differnt is that I close off the query with a ->get() in advance, and I use merge() instead of union()

```
$a = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
->where('col_a', '=' , 1)
->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))->get();

$b = Model::where('code', '=', $code)
->where('col_b', '=' , 1)
->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(layout, "normal", "split", "flip", "double-faced", "") ASC, layout'))->get();

$result = $a->merge($b);
```

Note: I don't have your data so I can't proof it work, but it least it work on my data so should worth your try

Comment: I added ->get(); to the end of your examples $a and $b.
The solution you provided sort of works but requires hitting the database for each one which is what I'm trying to avoid because I require multiple unions but this is currently the best answer.

Comment: It does'n work, when need to paginate merged result with right sort order

Comment: I did this to get proper results with datatable result $a->union($b)->get(); [Add get(); after union is applied]