# Union operator in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

How can I use sql `UNION` operator in eloquent ORM? I know I can use it in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` , but I want to do it with eloquent. I couldn't find anything about it in documentation neither in google. is it possible to do it?

Comment: Eloquent ORM doesn't have `union` method. Please describe what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent Union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756404/laravel-eloquent-union-query)

Comment: I'm trying to union multiple(two) queries, I dont want to send 2 quires

Comment: You could combine two eloquent collections but it doesnt have union method

Comment: @devnull what's wrong with sending two queries to get two collections (nested or separate)?

Comment: I'm trying to do simple thing and that's why don't want to send 2 queries, also I need relations and mutators, thats why I don't choose `querybuilder`, but as I see I will have to send 2 queries

Comment: Forget about how many queries you send. Eloquent uses a lot of queries when getting data so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `union()` method in eloquent in the same way as its in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions)