# All Latest Activity in One Page in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2

I am creating a Blog Website for my friend which she can Post a Blog, sometimes she will write a book with chapters and I got it all working.

Right now, I put it on different pages `Blog` and `Library`.

Does anyone know how can I make one page that will show the most recent activity on her website?

For example, when she will post a blog, it will show there as a recent activity that says she posted a blog and when she will write a book, it will also show there that she wrote a book.

That page will also show the title of the book or blog post.

Thank you!

By the way, I am using Laravel 5.6 and Vue JS

Answer (score 1):

**One Line Summary**, write an api that will fetch recent activities and use it in VueJs of the page you want to show recent activities.

**Details**

If you have two separate tables (i.e. models) for `blog_post` and `book_chapter`. Then [union these two models and get the latest 10 entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756404/laravel-eloquent-union-query). Ultimately these 10 entries are the most recent activities. To get latest 10, you can sort by `created_at` in `desc` and limit to 10.

Comment: i will try this sir and search more about it since I am new to laravel. thanks!

Comment: Comment here, whether it solves or not. If solves the issue don't forget to accept this answer. Check this if not checked already,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I tried it now but it seems like it gets only 2 of each record, I created 3 books and 4 blogs and i used union. it shows only 4 records

Comment: check your query and where constraints

Comment: i just used $books = Book::latest()->get(); and the blogs in the same way and then $result = $blogs->union($books); then compact it to show it in the view template

Comment: latest will return the last one. For this you are getting two - one from each model.

Comment: Use `take(10)` instead of `latest()`

Comment: latest() in laravel will return a collection of data in order from old to latest data.

Comment: @Imperatura it depends how the collection is ordered. If you want from old to new, sort from new to old, take(10) and sort again.

Comment: @Dimitri but right now my problem is that.. i have 5 blogs and 5 books.. when i union them I  get 7.. 5 blogs and 2 books

Comment: @Imperatura could this be because there is no information on 3 books you are requesting? Empty results/collections will be discarded in a union request as there is nothing to union with.