# Join Query in laravel without common in tables

Tags: laravel, mariadb

Want select all columns from three table without common column

```
  $data = DB::table('users')
         ->join('country.*','users.*')
         ->join('city.*', 'country.*')
         ->where('users.id', '=', $id)
         ->get();
```

Above query showing

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> error

Answer (score 0):

I personally never use Joins in laravel because you can easily just look up in various tables using the Models given an ID or a key; relationships are pretty easy and straightforward that way. But if you absolutely need to use Join, it seems like your syntax is missing a few parameters, like What is it joining based on? Just by skimming the laravel documentation, I found this example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Comment: i dont have a common columns for tables then how can i compare, then i want select whole table columns not particular columns

Comment: Then I think what you're looking for is a UNION rather than a JOIN. Take a look at the following links, they should help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756404/laravel-eloquent-union-query
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#unions

It is essentially running two select queries then combining the results, which seems to be what you want since there's no common column to join the tables.