# Order By Clause Overridden in Laravel Union Query Construction

Tags: sql-order-by, laravel-8, union, query-builder

I have two queries, `$querySelectedItems` and `$queryRemainingItems`, each retrieving a distinct set of items from the 'items' table.

```
$selecteditemids = [1,3,5,6];

$querySelectedItems = Item::whereIn('id', $selectedItemIds);

$queryRemainingItems = Item::orderBy('activated_at', 'desc')
                    ->whereNotIn('id', $selectedItemIds)
```

Now to combine both sets of items, I use the union method provided by Laravel's query builder.

```
$query = $querySelectedItems->union($queryRemainingItems);
$query->get();  //later
```

However, I encounter an issue where the `order by` clause specified in `$queryRemainingItems` is not being applied when using `union`.

When I observe the resulting items, the combination is correct: `$querySelectedItems` followed by `$queryRemainingItems`. But, despite specifying an `order by` clause in `$queryRemainingItems`, the order of items from this query is ascending on the `activated_at` column. Even if I don't explicitly mention or change the `order by` clause to descending within `$queryRemainingItems`, the behavior remains the same. It seems that the `union` method has its own ordering behavior.

Again, without `union`, if I use `merge()` that brings correct ordering:

```
$selectedItems = $querySelectedItems->get();
$remainingItems = $queryRemainingItems->get();
$mergedItems = $selectedItems->merge($remainingItems);
```

But this approach is not feasible due to project requirements.

How can I ensure that the `order by` clause specified in `$queryRemainingItems` is preserved when using `union` to combine both queries?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756404/laravel-eloquent-union-query) your question?