# How to fetch data from DB order by datetime closest to now or current date

Tags: mysql

How to fetch data from DB order by datetime closest to now or current date.

Below is my query, this will give idea about table structure.

```
SELECT o.id,
       p.price_quoted,
       p.discount,
       p.offer_price,
       p.amount_paid,
       o.user_id,
       s.subject,
       o.page_count,
       o.deadline,
       o.order_status,
       u.timezone
  FROM orders o
  JOIN payment p
    ON p.order_id = o.id
  JOIN subjects s
    ON s.id = o.subject_id
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = o.user_id
ORDER BY o.deadline
```

ORDER BY o.deadline is doing the work but I need to handle the case where deadline has already passed.

Suppose today's date is "2021-05-08" and in my database I have 3 records as below:

| deadline |
| --- |
| 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-05-22 |
| 2021-05-10 |

I want to get as below from Database:

| deadline |
| --- |
| 2021-05-10 |
| 2021-05-22 |
| 2021-05-01 |

As 2021-05-01 is past, so it should come in last
and future dates 2021-05-10, 2021-05-22 should be sorted as closest to today's date.

I am using MySQL and PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query to show nearest date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186962/sql-query-to-show-nearest-date)

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @El_Vanja this does not answer my question. Using this it will give past events with sorted as future ones, but I want past events to be sorted it should be displayed at the end, please see my example again, thanks

Comment: I missed that part. So you're not actually looking to sort by closest, you're looking to sort by something custom. Might want to do that sorting on the PHP side. If you still want to keep it on the query level, you could use this principle inside two separate subqueries (one for future, one for past dates) [inside a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683766/how-to-use-order-by-inside-union).